# How to get attempted log-in user name?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp v3.x

Below is my login function.

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
} //public function login()
```

I am trying to get the username who tried to log in. I tried reading http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html
I am not able to find the API to retrieve the username. How can this be done?

Comment: Guessing you can just access the post params like you'd do normally http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-parameters

Comment: Do you mean tried to login but not login succeeded ? or after login you want to get the name ?

Comment: @Alimon Karim, thanks for asking. I have found the answer myself. See answer provided.

Comment: @JimL, thanks to u, I found the answer. See answer provided.

Comment: @user768421 I just read the docs ;)

Comment: @JimL, I read the wrong docs. Should have read the controller docs. Didn't realize the answer was found there.

Comment: Read all the docs! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get all details for user :

```
$user_details = $this->Auth->User();
echo $user_details['username'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to hint from JimL, the answer is as follows;

```
$username = $this->request->data['username'];
```